# Крашится программа на моменте выделения памяти

Tags: c, указатели, память, структуры

Вообщем, на моменте выделения памяти(а именно realloc) для указателя крашится программа.
В отладке выводится такое сообщение: Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x0F62461D (ucrtbased.dll) в Laba 1 new.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xCDCDCDC4.

```
struct Strings **Input(int *len) {
    puts("Введите кол-во элементов структурного типа:");
    scanf_s("%d", len);
    CleanStdin();

    struct Strings **lines;
    lines = (struct Strings**)malloc((*len) * sizeof(struct Strings*));

    puts("Вводите строки:");
    int i;
    int j;
    char ch;
    for (i = 0; i < *len; i++) {
        lines[i] = (struct Strings*)malloc(sizeof(struct Strings));
        for (j = 0;; j++) {
            ch = getchar();
            CleanStdin();
            if (ch != '\n') {
                (lines[i] -> line) = (char*)realloc((lines[i] -> line), (j + 1) * sizeof(char));
                lines[i]->line[j] = ch;
            }
            else break;
        }
        if(!j) lines[i]->len = j + 1;
        else lines[i]->len = 0;
    }
    return lines;
}
```

Comment: `x = realloc(x, ...);` -- так делать не надо. (Это помимо ответа ниже)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вы выделили память для структуры в предложении

```
lines[i] = (struct Strings*)malloc(sizeof(struct Strings));
```

то члены данных структуры не инициализированы и содержат произвольные значения в том числе это относится и к члену данных с именем `line`.

Поэтому когда в данном предложении

```
(lines[i] -> line) = (char*)realloc((lines[i] -> line), (j + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

вызывается функция `realloc` для указателя `line`, то имеет место неопределенное поведение, которое и привело к возникновению исключения.

Вам следует инициализировать этот член данных нулевым указателем после выделения памяти для объекта структуры. Например,

```
lines[i] = (struct Strings*)malloc(sizeof(struct Strings));
line[i]->line = NULL;
Line[i]->len = 0;
```

К тому же данные предложения

```
if(!j) lines[i]->len = j + 1;
   ^^^
else lines[i]->len = 0;
```

неверные. Скорей всего имеется в виду, что если `j` не равно 0, то устанавливается значение члена данных `len` значением `j + 1`. То есть более правильно условие предложения `if` должно быть записано как

```
if( j ) lines[i]->len = j + 1;
   ^^^
else lines[i]->len = 0;
```

Но, тем не менее, значение `j + 1` также будет неверным. Допустим, что в самом начале цикла была выделена память размером `j + 1`. Так как изначально `j` равно 0, то был выделен один байт. После первой итерации цикла `j` станет равным 1. Если после этого был выход по `break` во второй итерации цикла, то члену данных структуры `len`, должно быть присвоено значение 1, то есть значение, содержащееся в `j`. Однако вы присваиваете значение равное `j + 1`, то есть 2. Поэтому правильно будет записать (безусловно)

```
lines[i]->len = j;
```

Обратите внимание, что вы не дополняете строку завершающим нулем.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за содержательный и быстрый ответ!

Comment: Насчет строк, конкретно в этой задаче я использую не строки, а массив символов. (Ибо зачем в структуре присваивать еще и длину строки, если можно воспользоваться функцией strlen(), а так , хоть не бессмыслица получается.

Comment: @ReCursia Логично. Я лишь хочу отметить, что если нулевой символ отсутствует, то могут возникнуть проблемы с выводом этих строк в выходной поток и с применением стандартных функций сравнения строк.